# Regular expression for string in Inno Setup

Tags: regex, inno-setup, pascalscript

In Inno Setup tool (Windows OS)

```pascal
InstallDir: string;
```

I have a string `InstallDir` which contains  `C:\-=[]\.,';`

I want to set a regular expression pattern as below

```
^([a-zA-Z]:)\\([0-9a-zA-Z_\\\s\.\-\(\)]*)$
```

Ex:
It should be `c:\`< `A` to `Z` / `a` to `z` > or number or `_` and so on (means a valid path).

I could not find any function in Inno Setup, which tells it supports regular expression for string operations.

Can any body help me out to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

No, Inno Setup does not support regular expressions.

You may be able to invoke PowerShell for that, but that's an overkill.

You do not need a regular expression for your check:

```pascal
function IsPathValid(Path: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Path := Uppercase(Path);
  Result :=
    (Length(Path) >= 3) and
    (Path[1] >= 'A') and (Path[1] <= 'Z') and
    (Path[2] = ':') and
    (Path[3] = '\');

  if Result then
  begin
    for I := 3 to Length(Path) do
    begin
      case Path[I] of
        '0'..'9', 'A'..'Z', '\', ' ', '.', '-', '(', ')':
          else 
        begin
          Result := False;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

(The code [requires Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38621801/850848), what you should use anyway and it is the only version as of current Inno Setup 6).

---

Similar questions:

- [Basic email validation within Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2001255/850848)
- [Wildcard characters in Inno Setup (test if there is any value after fixed string prefix)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53390206/850848)

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, Really appricated your quick response. I will try this and let you know.

You  really helped me :)