# Wildcard characters in Inno Setup (test if there is any value after fixed string prefix)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there some wildcard characters for Inno Setup? I am trying to go through string and if there is some value that I'm searching for, the program should return 1 (I'm using `Pos()` function that already does what I need), but my problem here is that the part of string that I'm searching for is not static, so I need some wildcard character like `*` that can replace one or more characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no pattern matching functionality in Inno Setup Pascal Script until recently.  Since 6.1, you can use the [`WildcardMatch` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wildcardmatch) *(as the answer by @Roman shows)*.

---

If you are stuck with an older version, or if you need a custom matching, you can use a function like this:

```pascal
function AnythingAfterPrefix(S: string; Prefix: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := 
     (Copy(S, 1, Length(Prefix)) = Prefix) and
     (Length(S) > Length(Prefix));
end;
```

And use it like:

```pascal
if AnythingAfterPrefix(S, 'Listing connections...') then
```

You may want to add [`TrimRight`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_trimright) to ignore trailing spaces:

```pascal
if AnythingAfterPrefix(TrimRight(S), 'Listing connections...') then
```

---

Similar questions:

- [Regular expression for string in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47263968/850848)
- [Basic email validation within Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2001255/850848)

Comment: Thanks @Martin Prikryl, the king of Inno Setup on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions) there are now

```
function IsWildcard(const Pattern: String): Boolean;
function WildcardMatch(const Text, Pattern: String): Boolean;
```

maybe they were added recently. Should do what you needed.